# Update requestdigest value

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, post, request-digest

I have a custom sp 2013 page with content editor webpart, js referred from site assets,

I am using rest api to perform crud

If I do a post request, I am passing the $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
But my scenario is some of my users are opening the page and hitting the save btn after 30 mins, so the digest values is expired and getting 403 forbidden issue,

So I used this line to update the request digest
Before my post ajax call.

UpdateFormDigest("http://sitecollectionurl", _spFormDigestRefreshInterval);

But I am getting cannot convert primitive data type int32 error after that.

Any idea or different ways to update the requestdigest value when expired.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the error?  Is the error being thrown by `UpdateFormDigest()`, or is it being thrown by the server when you try to make your REST call?  Can you provide an example of more of your code so we can see better where the error is happening?

Comment: RequestDigest is updated successfully, I checked by logging it .  but the next line my ajax call to post request starts, there only error is coming sounds like i have to wait for this updateformdigest to finish for a second etc.

Comment: I don't think so, if `UpdateFormDigest()` does not throw an error, and if you know that the request digest updated successfully by logging it, than I don't think the error you are seeing has to do with the request digest.  I think it has to do with the data you are trying to write to SP.  "cannot convert primitive data type int32" sounds like maybe a `JSON.stringify()` error?

Comment: Yes thats correct! I have given all my data in JSON.stringify() and posting it. with out this update function this code works correctly. But when I add this update function above my ajax call, the error is comming "Cannot convert a primitive value to the expected type 'Edm.Int32'. See the inner exception for more details."